# PhpStorm NuxJs plugins: marked as unresolved variable from component when called this.$myPlugin

Tags: plugins, nuxt.js, phpstorm, webstorm

PhpStorm 2021.2.2
Nuxt @ v2.15.8

I'm using Nuxt plugins in my project. PhpStorm doesn't recognize the variable when I'm calling the plugin from a component.

From my component:

```
this.$repositories.mediaObjects
```

From "nuxt.config.js":

```
plugins: [
    '@/plugins/repository',
  ],
```

From "plugins/repository.js":

```
import createRepository from '~/api/Repository.js'

export default (ctx, inject) => {

  const repositoryWithAxios = createRepository(ctx.$axios)

  const repositories = {
    categories: repositoryWithAxios('categories'),
  }

  inject('repositories', repositories)
}
```

The plugin work well but PhpStorm won't recognize `this.$repositories` as a known variable

[image: capture here]

Does anyone has a clue on how to handle this?

Comment: It looks related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51041.

Comment: Yes, that it. I'll stay tune on it. Thanks @Oksana

Answer (score 0):

So as mentioned in the comments, this seems to be an IDE internal issue but heres a small workaround also found in the jetbrains issue, I am not using PHPStorm, instead WebStorm but the issue is the same for me.

Create an `index.d.ts` in the root of the project and add this:

```
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $yourInjection: <Type>
  }
}
```

And then also include the index.d.ts in your tsconfig like so

```
  "include": ["index.d.ts"],
```

Restart your IDE and then it should work.

this was done in nuxt version: `"^2.15.8"`